# Is there a branchless way to move number towards another number without exceeding it?

Tags: c++, math, optimization, floating-point, branchless

I want to implement a function conforming to the following interface and contract:

```
void move_towards(float& value, float target, float step) 
    // Moves `value` towards `target` by `step`. 
    // `value` will never go beyond `target`, but can match it.
    // If `step == 0.0f`, `value` is unchanged.
    // If `step > 0.0f`, `std::abs(target - value)` decreases.
    // If `step < 0.0f`, the behavior is undefined.
```

The idea is to use this function to gradually move an existing floating point value towards another, without ever exceeding the target. This is useful - for example - to perform linear transitions between values as part of the execution of a game loop.

Here's an example test case:

```
float value = 5.0f;
move_towards(value,  10.f,  1.f); assert(value ==  6.0f);
move_towards(value,  10.f,  1.f); assert(value ==  7.0f);
move_towards(value, -5.f,   5.f); assert(value ==  2.0f);
move_towards(value, -5.f,   5.f); assert(value == -3.0f);
move_towards(value, -5.f,   5.f); assert(value == -5.0f);
move_towards(value, -5.f,   5.f); assert(value == -5.0f);
move_towards(value,  0.f,  15.f); assert(value ==  0.0f);
```

I tried a few branchless ideas using a combination of `std::copysign` and `std::clamp`, but they always failed in some edge cases. In the end, I resorted to using a branchy version:

```
void move_towards(float& value, float target, float step) 
{
    if (value < target)
    {
        value += step;
        if (value > target)
        {
            value = target;
        }
    }
    else if (value > target)
    {
        value -= step;
        if (value < target)
        {
            value = target;
        }
    }
}
```

[**live on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v8hY4bzMh)

- Is it possible to implement `move_towards` in order to produce branchless instructions?
- If not, is it possible to at least minimize the number of branches?
- Regardless, what version provides the best run-time performance?

Comment: I'd start by using `std::min` and `std::max` which should compile to branchless code on platforms that support it. Then you reduce the problem to just deciding whether to use min or max. Edit : [contains only one branch](https://godbolt.org/z/3YGqKdKz3).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I'll experiment with `std::min` and `std::max`, however note that your solution doesn't conform to the contract. `step` must always be zero or positive.

Comment: You're right that I got the intended functionality wrong. Though I think a correct implementation can still be done with a single branch using min and max.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: avoiding the use of `std::min` and `std::max` seems to result in a faster execution (see https://quick-bench.com/q/8uxP0iLPlGWu4ajXnqnKhSjyArg). Maybe reducing the number of branches in this case doesn't mean that the final code will be faster...

Comment: What should be the desired behaviour when `value + step == value && step > 0`?

Comment: The impact of branches, assuming branch prediction is being used, fundamentally depends on the unpredictability of the branch. You should try to compare them for the worst case, a much larger series of shuffled directions. Then if the branching version is better, you know the alternative is not useful. I'd also recommend you benchmark on the target platform, as the specific architecture can also have an impact. Finally, if you have a real application for this, I'd profile the solutions in real use cases to get the most meaningful results.

Comment: @eerorika: how could that happen? Do you mean `value + step == target && step != 0`?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo It happens when absolute value is much greater than step.

Comment: @eerorika: I see. I am fine with that situation being undefined/indeterminate.

Comment: Can we assume that you already tried [`std::lerp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lerp) and found it too expansive?

Comment: What do you expect to happen in a situation like `step > 0` and `target == value + 0.1*step`?   It doesn't matter if `value` is increased or decreased by `step` - in both cases `std::abs(target - value)` increases.     Your requirement can't be met in that case, even without the consideration of branching or not.

Comment: I did some run-time benchmarking between a few approaches: https://quick-bench.com/q/f_JzG6jzlIQ0yocbyEqJh2Wku5o

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I have removed the `c` tag.

Answer (score 5):

The desired result is the median of `value - step`, `value + step`, and `target`, so this works:

```
void move_towards(float &value, float target, float step) 
{
    value = std::max(value - step, std::min(value + step, target));
}
```

To see this, consider the cases where `target` lies below, between, or above `value - step` and `value + step`:

- If `target` ≤ `value - step` < `value + step`, then `value` can take a full `step` down toward `target`, so we want `value - step`.
- If `value - step` < `target` < `value + step`, then `value` cannot take a full `step` toward `target` (which might be in either direction), so we want `target`.
- If `value - step` < `value + step` ≤ `target`, then `value` can take a full `step` up toward `target`, so we want `value + step`.

In each case, we want the middle value.

Testing shows GCC generates two instructions fewer if we swap the `std::max` operands, likely just because it works better with where the operands happen to be in registers:

```
void move_towards(float &value, float target, float step) 
{
    value = std::max(std::min(value + step, target), value - step);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the approach that Francois Andrieux was hinting at.
Have you tried this?  It's just one branch.

```
void move_towards(float& value, float target, float step) {
    value = target < value 
        ? std::max(value - step, target)
        : std::min(value + step, target);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jxKP6oT1h

Answer (score 1):

You can do this completely branch-free, if you have a reasonably modern processor target (with branch-free selection from two floating-point values).

The approach would be to formulate the problem as follows:

Compute a "signed step" value that is either `+step` or `-step`, depending on whether `target > value` or `target < value`. Find the median of `target`, `value` and `value + signed step`. Finding the median can be done by sorting, but for three elements you can also just combine the elements with an invertible operation and apply the inverted operation on the combination with the maximum and minimum of the three values. For `float`, invertible operations are a bit of a problem, because addition/subtraction are not associative. However, in your comments you said that you do not care about the case where the target and value have extremely different magnitudes, so addition and subtraction work decently well. A better solution would bitwise convert to an unsigned integer type of the same width, then use `xor` as the invertible operation, then convert the median bit pattern back to float.

Here's the solution on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qcEnfvTTc), and in the answer:

```
void move_towards(float& value, float target, float step) {
    auto sstep = (target > value ? step : -step);
    auto nval = value + sstep;
    value = value + target + nval -
        std::min(std::min(value, target), nval) -
        std::max(std::max(value, target), nval);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> any branchless version?

Use the sign of `target - value` to select a function by index.

```
float move_towards(float value, float target, float step) {
  static float (*f[2])(float a, float b) = {fminf, fmaxf};
  float diff = target - value;
  bool index = signbit(diff);
  step = copysignf(step, 0 - index);
  return f[index](target, value + step);
}
```

Code is a C solution.  Leave it to OP to translate to C++ as needed.

Comment: I like the idea, but your solution doesn't conform to the specification of the function -- `step` is always supposed to be positive, and the direction `value` moves towards is determined by `target`. See how the tests fail here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5rfMrEr16

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Hmmmmm.

Comment: Here's how you could do it: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GM8sbr3Yb

Comment: However, this is pretty slow at run-time: https://quick-bench.com/q/Y-fFiSIacdFY2VN2VlQu63dA98s 

Cool concept, though.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Updated - maybe an issue when `value == target` in some cases.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo "pretty slow" ? Is the goal _branchless_ as in the title or _speed_ or what?

Comment: Good point, my initial goal was to be branchless as I expected that to be faster, but I actually care about run-time speed more. I think it might be too late for this question to be about speed, but I'd appreciate trying to maximize that as well.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo "branchless is a valid goal, fast or slow, to create a uniform run time regardless of argument values.   This prevent leaking information in secure apps.  Yes " actually care about run-time speed more" was a trap we are now in because rather than detailing that goal, folks often [assume](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Assume) branchless is expected  to be faster.  To get _fast_ code help, do not just post the function code (that part good), also post the test harness to assess time.